# how much of red green and blue light is necessary to make black

Tags: visible-light

Can you please let us know how much of red green and blue light is necessary to make black and explain the reasoning

Thank you

Comment: What is the context of the question? When would it make sense to "make black" by combining red and green light (or any colors of light)?

Comment: I don't think you can get black by combining any non-zero amounts of RGB light...

Comment: Black means no light but in painting you can combine colours to make black because all the light is absorbed and none is reflected for you to see.

Answer (score 3):

Well, black's hex code is #000000 or (R,G,B) = (0,0,0). You can think of black as 'the absence of colour', so by removing all colours (setting everything to zero), you get black.